# Button to download CSV document not working in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, download, blob

I have a csv file in my directory that I want to trigger a direct download for upon clicking a download button.

I used the file-saver library and a fetch request to handle everything.

here is the function:

```
  const handleDownload = () => {
    fetch('public/data/COW2021001887-I589Data.csv', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/csv'
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => saveAs(blob, 'file.csv'))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  };
```

But when I click the button, i get an excel spreadsheet that only has an HTML template with it..

attached is a picture of the path, in case that's the issue because it's theonly thing I can think. Of course i imported  save as from the file-saver library and this function is the handler for the button.

Any advice would be appreciated. I've tried triggering hte download a few different ways but always end up with an html template document (also pictured)

[the CSV with the html template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhZzf.png)
[the paths of the files i'm working on Render landing page near the bottom, the file is in public/data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH6c3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the library to save the URL directly?

```
const FileSaver = require('file-saver');

const handleDownload = () => {
  FileSaver.saveAs("public/data/COW2021001887-I589Data.csv", "file.csv");
};
```

Also, are you using an older version of file-saver? I'm not seeing the `.blob()` syntax in the documentation, but only the `new Blob` syntax:

```
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using FileSaver.saveAs didn't work either.
I'm using file-saver 2.0.5, i'm not very well versed in how blobs work so i'm not sure if that's what i'm messing up

Answer (score 0):

instead of `response.blob()`, try using the `new` operator like this:

```
  const handleDownload = () => {
    fetch('public/data/COW2021001887-I589Data.csv', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/csv'
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
          // double check the response object is what you want here
          const blob = new Blob([response], {type: "text/csv"});
          FileSaver.saveAs("file.csv");
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  };
```